# How to initialize the database with your test data for each module? Pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

For each application in the project, you need to write tests. Also for each application you first need to upload your test data, which, after passing all the module tests, must be deleted.

I found several solutions, but none of them seems to me optimal

First:
in file `conftest.py` in each app I override method `django_db_setup`, but in this case, the data is not deleted after passing the tests in the module, and become available for other applications. 
In theory, with the help of `yield` you can delete all the data after passing the tests.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command('loaddata', './apps/accounts/fixtures/accounts.json')
        call_command('loaddata', './apps/activation/fixtures/activation.json')
        call_command('loaddata', './apps/questionnaire/fixtures/questionnaire.json')
        yield 
        # delete test data
```

Second: in the class with tests write such a setup

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(self, db):
    call_command('loaddata', './apps/accounts/fixtures/accounts.json')
    call_command('loaddata', './apps/activation/fixtures/activation.json')
    call_command('loaddata', './apps/questionnaire/fixtures/questionnaire.json')
```

In this case, the data will be loaded exactly as many times as there will be tests in the module, which also seems to be not quite correct.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understood your problem, that's why I deleted the answer. I have tested the module-scoped fixture solution on a multi-app django project, the data is deleted after each module finishes executing; the isolation is achieved by loading the selection of app-specific fixture files.

Comment: I will try to explain again. There are applications for which test data should be isolated from each other, respectively. In the example above, all 3 json files are needed to test a single module. And I found 2 solutions that are shown above. But in the first it is necessary to delete the data by hand, and in the second for each test in the module these 3 files will be loaded. The ideal solution I think is identical to the ```setUp``` function in the standard django tests. But how I understand it, it's just not there :(

Comment: for each application I need to upload my test data, and after the end of the tests, delete them so that they do not conflict with the following tests. Or to make setup functions which will be caused once for each class with tests

Comment: Making sure test order will not affect the tests result is not that easy if you are not loading the fixture again for every test and discarding data afterwards. IMHO loading the data again every time seems like the right thing to do.

Comment: This is logical, but it will increase the test run time.

Comment: this is an old thread but why not settings a different sqlite database test for each database with thier own initial datas?...just a question

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this in my own tests :

```py
from pytest_django.fixtures import _django_db_fixture_helper

@pytest.fixture(autoscope='module')
def setup_db(request, django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    _django_db_fixture_helper(request,·django_db_blocker)
    call_command('loaddata', 'path/to/fixture.json')
```

I think that pytest_django should export the _django_db_fixture_helper in its official API as a factory fixture.